# How to check a checkbox dynamically Knockout js Magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am not able to check my checkbox dynamically in knockoutjs.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="giftoptions" id="printedCard" data-bind="checked: getObservable('printedCard')()"/>

<label for="printedCard" class="label"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Gift receipt, gift box and card (Complimentary)'"></span></label>
```

The checkbox only gets checked after reloading the page.
How to check the checkboxes without reloading the page?

On the contrary, textboxes are getting updated

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" data-bind="value: getObservable('sender'), attr: { id: 'gift-message-whole-from-' + index }"  placeholder="From (Optional)"/> </div>
```

After the post-call when I call the  `getObservable('sender')` on the other `HTML page` it shows me the recent typed values

```
 <!-- ko if: getObservable('message') -->
      <div class="gift-message-summary">
      <span data-bind="i18n: 'Message:'"></span>
      <!-- ko text: getObservable('message') --><!-- /ko -->
      </div>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I have been having problems with this aswell but can't seem to find a solution to it, please let me know if you find something!